# RPM broken after removing nss3

Tags: rpm, nss

I was trying to remove some unneeded packages from RPM and I removed nss-3.12.8 using the --force flag (stupid, I know).  Now all RPM commands aside from --help return instantly and do nothing.  I've tried -rebuilddb and that command does nothing as well.  I'm at a loss as to how I can get rpm up and working again, please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is you're screwed. However, here's what you can *try*:

1. Get a copy of nss RPMs. Probably both 32- and 64-bit if you're on the latter.
2. `rpm2cpio nss.rpm | cpio -div` from the root of the machine. That will put at least the libraries, etc. into the right places.
3. If you can *now* run `rpm`, re-install the RPMs. That way the DB will have it, and any pre/post scripts will execute.
4. Remember not to use `--force` again unless you really know it's OK.

If that doesn't work, you might be able to boot from a rescue CD and do the same from the mounted hard drive, e.g. `/mnt/sysimage/`.

Comment: Thanks Aaron.  The rpm2cpio restored my ability to run rpm -i and -e, but -qa and --rebuilddb are still broken in the same fashion as before.  Stuck yet again!

Comment: After trying a bunch of things, RPM finally works again!  I think reinstalling a few of the base RPMs (including the RPM rpm itself) with --force put all the dependencies back in place.  Thanks again.